# Sending generic class with ajax call

Tags: ajax, controller

I'm trying out a generic approach when calling an MVC controller via ajax. So, if we have something like this:

```
url: '/ChartReporting/GetChartReportingResults'
data: JSON.stringify({Type: 'Pie', some more properties...})
```

Is there a way to not have to specify the concrete class in the controller method as in:

`public JsonResult GetChartReportingResults(ChartingData chartingData)...`

I'd love to be able to say `ChartingBase` instead of `ChartingData`. `ChartingBase` would be an abstract class. So the params I pass within the `JSON.stringify` would be a class of type `ChartingBase`. I can easily do this type of thing once inside the controller but to get this generic info over in the first place is the tricky part. Basically, Im trying to have one method to use for all charting needs based on this `ChartingBase` class.

Hope this makes sense.

David

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this and decided to just simply pass in an array of key/value pairs with paramname, param value. I can easily build a paramlist for the proc with that info.

Thanks for letting me vent and think this through myself. Of course ideas from others would have been cool too :-)

David